# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.3.3

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

Error :

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.3.3.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.3.3/gradle-4.3.3.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.3.3/gradle-4.3.3.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.3.3/gradle-4.3.3.pom
Required by:
    project :
```

build.gradle(Project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.3.3"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blogger"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

This is while Trying to connect to fire base .(Add Firebase to your Android app)
https://console.firebase.google.com

Kindly help I have downloaded google-services.json and synced it as well  and it gives this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version `4.3.3` of the android gradle plugin **doesn't** exist.

Use:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
```

**Don't confuse** it with the google play services plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

The version you are trying does not exist.

You can choose alternate versions available in the link below.

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Studio 4.2 (Beta 3 in my case) and it's a react-native project, it won't point to the gradle file with the broken gradle reference, so you might want to re-install node_modules just in case you accidentally changed it.